# How to update data by select random row value from another table

Tags: oracle, select, random, sql-update

I have three tables `A`, `B`, `C`, and I want to randomly take a row from the `col_b` column of the table `B` then update it to the table `A`. Table `C` is the subtable of Table `B`, which is used to filter the data of Table `B`.
Here is my sql statement:

```
update a a
   set a.col_a_b =
       (select t.col_b
          from (select a1.col_a, b1.col_b, a1.rn_var
                  -- the number 6 is because I only have 6 rows of data,
                  -- and the real situation should be the total number of conditions in table b
                  from (select a0.col_a, TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1, 6)) rn_var 
                          from a a0) a1
                  left join (select b.col_b, rownum rn
                              from b b
                             where exists (select 1
                                      from c c
                                     where b.id = c.col_b_id
                                       and c.col_c = 'c1')) b1
                    on a1.rn_var = b1.rn) t
         where t.col_a = a.col_a);
```

I found a strange phenomenon:

- If I remove `a1.rn_var` (line `from (select a1.col_a, b1.col_b, a1.rn_var`), it doesn't work as my expected
- On the basis of the above, if I replace `exists` with `left join` (or `join`), the result is the same
- If I reomve both `a1.rn_var` and `exists`, it will work fine.

I know there may be a better way to implement it, but who can tell me why?

**Update:**

Actually, it is caused by this sql:

```
select a1.col_a, b1.col_b -- remove a1.rn_var
  from (select a0.col_a, TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1, 6)) rn_var from a a0) a1
  left join (select b.col_b, rownum rn
               from b b
              where exists (select 1
                       from c c
                      where b.id = c.col_b_id
                        and c.col_c = 'c1')) b1
    on a1.rn_var = b1.rn
 -- this is for better display of results
 where a1.col_a = 'a1';
```

In the above sql, I may get multiple rows of data or column `b1.col_b` is empty, as shown below:

```
a1  b1
a1  b2
a1  b4
------------------------------------------------
a1     -- here is null
```

In addition, each value of column `a1.col_a` is the same, I mean, if value `a1` has multiple rows, then value `a2` (and so on) has the same result, like this:

```
a1  b2
a1  b4
a1  b5
a2  b2
a2  b4
a2  b5
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a random number and order by that random number to get random records.

I prefer using the following technique:

```
UPDATE A A
SET
    A.COL_A_B = (
        SELECT
            COL_B
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    COL_B,
                    TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, COUNT(1) OVER())) RANDOM_NUMBER  --GENERATES RANDOM NUMBER
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT DISTINCT
                            B.COL_B -- FETCHING DISTINCT RESULT
                        FROM
                            B B
                            -- EXISTS IS CONVERTED INTO JOIN
                            JOIN C C ON ( B.ID = C.COL_B_ID 
                                          AND C.COL_C = 'c1' )
                    )
                ORDER BY
                    RANDOM_NUMBER -- ORDERING IS DONE BY RANDOM NUMBER
                FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY -- FETCHING ONLY FIRST ROW FROM ORDERED RECORDS
            )
    )
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, it's work for me. If you could tell me the reason for the problem I am describing, I will be more happy.

Comment: First of all, your random number rn_var can only contains 6 numbers and only first 6 values from table b   is picked in your case. And for more details, you need to tell me what was actual result while you were removing the columns mentioned in the question

Comment: It is my fault, I have updated my question and added some examples of actual results.

Comment: Yes, analyzed the data. It is because you used 6 random numbers only and in my example, i have used rowcount of table b as random number.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My idea is that I count the number of rows in table `b` at first, then take random numbers. Is this wrong?